# Toxicity of stannous fluoride in toothpaste?

Tags: biochemistry

I recently purchased a new brand of toothpaste, and when I looked at the medicinal ingredients, it listed stannous fluoride 0.454% w/w, instead of the regular sodium fluoride. I was a bit concerned because I thought that tin was toxic to humans, and that it might be absorbed in the mouth.

A couple of studies like [this one](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/27838508) say that stannous fluoride is great, and I can't seem to find any studies on how toxic tin ions are to humans, but on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tin(II)_fluoride) it says that stannous fluoride readily forms tin metal and ions in water. Should I be worried?

> Readily soluble in water, SnF2 is hydrolysed. At low concentration, it forms species such as SnOH+, Sn(OH)2 and Sn(OH)3−. At higher concentrations, predominantly polynuclear species are formed, including Sn2(OH)22+ and Sn3(OH)42+. Aqueous solutions readily oxidise to form insoluble precipitates of SnIV, which are ineffective as a dental prophylactic.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Please take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site and [edit] your question accordingly. In particular note that personal medical questions are **not** appropriate for this site. ——— Please consult with a dentist or other medical professional instead — any advice on medical subjects obtained over the internet should be regarded with extreme suspicion. Thanks! 

Comment: https://fluoridealert.org/studies/acute01/